Counterexample of switching Pullback and exterior derivative
We have a theorem in class where for a $C^2$ function $F:U \to V$ and a differential $C^1$ $k$-form $\alpha \in \Omega(V)$, we have $d(F^*\alpha) = F^*(d\alpha)$. I would guess that the statement is wrong for a $C^1$ function, however I have not managed to come up with an counterexample. I would be glad if someone can provide a counterexample for a $C^1$ function $F$.

How do you differentiate $F^*\alpha$ if it is only a $C^0$ form? Try writing down an explicit function $F\colon\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ that is $C^1$ but not $C^2$.

If you define $d$ and $F^*$ using the weak derivative (I.e., in the sense of distributions), then the identity is always true.

@Deane would you be so kind and elaborate on the definition of the weak derivative, for $d$ and $F^*$.

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$I'll sketch what I have in mind, but I have not checked the details. Also, I appear to require that $U$ and $V$ are Riemannian manifolds and $F$ is a diffeomorphism. The basic idea is to define $F^*$ and $d$ in terms of their adjoint operators.
Let $U$ be a smooth Riemannian $n$-manifold. Let $\Omega_k^1(U)$ denote the space of compactly supported $C^k$ $1$-forms. A generalized $m$-form of order $-k$ is a continuous linear map
\begin{align*}
  \beta: \Omega_k^{n-m}(U) \rightarrow \R.
\end{align*}
Any compactly supported smooth differential form $\beta$ is such a generalized form by setting
\begin{align*}
\beta(\omega) = \int_U \beta\wedge\omega.
\end{align*}
If $F: U \rightarrow V$ is a $C^{k+1}$ map, then the pushforward of $\beta$ is the continuous linear map
\begin{align*}
  F_*\beta: \Omega_k^{n-m}(V) \rightarrow \R,
\end{align*}
where for any $\omega\in\Omega_k^{n-m}(V)$,
\begin{align*}
  F_*\beta(\omega) &= \beta(F^*\omega).
\end{align*}
If $F$ is a $C^{k+1}$ diffeomorphism, then we can define the pullback of a $m$-form $\alpha$ of order $-k$ on $V$ to be
\begin{align*}
  F^*\alpha = (F^{-1})_*\alpha
\end{align*}
On the other hand, if $\alpha$ is a generalized $m+1$-form of order $-k+1$ on $U$, then the (weak) exterior derivative $d\alpha$ is a generalized $m$-form of order $-k$ such that for any $\omega \in \Omega_k^{n-m}(U)$
\begin{align*}
  d\alpha(\omega) &= \alpha(d^*\omega),
\end{align*}
where $d^*$ is the adjoint of $d$ with respect to the Riemannian metric.
To prove that $dF^*\alpha = F^*d\alpha$ for a generalized $k$-form on $V$, you have to confirm that if $\alpha$ is smooth, the definitions above of $d$ and $F^*$ agree with the standard definition. There is then a standard argument that if $dF^* = F^*d$ holds for smooth forms, then it holds for generalized forms.

Thanks for the detailed answer
